# How can i join json objects and adding a new attribute inside of

Tags: javascript

I have some json objects, i want to join all of the objects only in one

i have this input

```
a:[{h:1, i:2}]
b:[{j:1, k:2}]
c:[{l:1, m:2}]
```

i need this output

```
[{type: a, h:1, i:2}, {type: a, o:1, p:2}, {type: b, j:1, k:2}, {type: c, l:1, m:2}]
```

i was trying:

```js
const a = {"a":[{"h":1, "i":2}]}
const b = {"b":[{"j":1, "k":2}]}
const c = {"c":[{"l":1, "m":2}]}

const result = {};
let key;

for (key in a) {
  if(a.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    result[key] = a[key];
  }
}


for (key in b) {
  if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    result[key] = b[key];
  }
}

console.log('b', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do if for any number of inputs with this code. Hope it helps:

```js
const data = [
  {"a":[{"h":1, "i":2}]},
  {"b":[{"j":1, "k":2}]},
  {"c":[{"l":1, "m":2}]}
];

const result = data.map((dataItem) => {
  const key = Object.keys(dataItem)[0];
  const valuesObject = dataItem[key][0];
  return {
    type: key,
    ...valuesObject
  };
});

console.log(result);
```